# Why is Samsung Galaxy S (Captivate) USB not supported in my Honda Pilot?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, usb

Any thoughts on how to resolve the "USB not supported" error my vehicle (Honda Pilot) displays when I connect the phone (Galaxy S Captivate) via the USB jack?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using the same USB cable that you use any other time?  The reason I ask is because I have a Captivate and due to how the connection is recessed, it is very picky on the cable - the part of the cable right above the micro USB side, and it will report a bad device.  If you are using the same cable, then nevermind.

Comment: Why would'nt you just use a stereo cable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That USB input in the Honda Pilot only supports certain drivers.  It looks like it has support for standard flash thumb drives and iPod products.  Android comes preloaded with the drivers necessary to communicate with windows so until Honda updates the stereos driver support or someone puts the necessary drivers to interface with the Pilot on your device I believe you will be out of luck.

Comment: Thanks for the response... I guess I wrongly assumed that all USB connected devices follow some standard that allows for playing mp3 without additional drivers.

Comment: I think that for all intents and purposes it'll operate that way most of the time (when talking about conventional computers) because Android pre-loads driver for most OS's and most OS's probably have the necessary drivers built in to.  Good luck and I hope that Dr.Dredel's suggestion works.

Comment: if it has support for standard flash thumb drives, then the mass storage option should work, in theory.  The device behaves like a standard thumb drive in that situation, but of course, Eric is right and at the end of the day, if the driver is wrong then you're going to get bubkis.

Comment: I was under the impression that it operated as a standard thumb drive because Android has drivers for all the major os version preloaded.

Answer (score 3):

do you have the USB set to the right setting?
settings->Applications->USB Settings->[Mass Storage or Media Player] 
Try all the different settings, it's not obvious which one the car is happy with (if any)

Also under settings -> Applications -> Development try turning on [USB Debugging].

Comment: Thanks for the response...i'll give it a try and report back if it works.

Comment: After testing...it would appear that drivers are missing as Matt suggested.